# Adding a group of headers to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I need to append a group of additional headers (as blank columns) to an existing dataframe; the corresponding values will be added in a later process. Please, advise, thanks!

Comment: So you just want to add a few extra blank columns to your `DataFrame`? Are those column headers stored in a list?

Comment: Yes, they are stored in  a list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way, I've included some sample data.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3],
                   'c2': [1, 1, 1],
                   'c3': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'c4': ['a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'cat': ['x', 'x', 'y']})

# These are the column headers you want to add
cols_to_add = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

### Code:

```
df = df.assign(**dict((col, '') for col in cols_to_add))
```

### Output:

```
   c1  c2 c3 c4 cat a b c d e
0   1   1  a  a   x          
1   2   1  b  a   x          
2   3   1  c  a   y
```

Explanation: `DataFrame.assign` allows you to assign columns to the DataFrame. You can pass it an unpacked dictionary as keyword arguments to assign multiple columns at once, in this case with the column name given by the names in our list, and the values as the empty string.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with a dataframe consisting of empty columns:

```
cols_to_add = list('abcde')
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=cols_to_add))
```

Comment: Just beautiful!